# How can I get the value of a bootstrap4 checkbox?

Tags: checkbox, bootstrap-4

I have the following checkbox:

```
<label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="modal_checkbox">
     <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
     <span class="custom-control-description">Do not show me this again.</span>
</label>
```

But I don't know how to get the value of the checkbox using jquery. I tried to get the attr or the prop of the above classes and ID but I get an "undefined"

Comment: This might be bcoz you dont have value attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is bcoz you dont have value attribute. Check this code.

```js
$(function() {
  console.log($("#modal_checkbox").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="modal_checkbox" value="my-value">
     <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
     <span class="custom-control-description">Do not show me this again.</span>
</label>
```

If you want to get the value on checkbox check do this

```js
$(function() {
      $("#modal_checkbox").click(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
          console.log($(this).val());
        }
      });
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="modal_checkbox" value="my-value">
         <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
         <span class="custom-control-description">Do not show me this again.</span>
    </label>
```